# Is this 'ok' practice in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a wrapper function in JavaScript that provides some helpful methods for a .Net control embedded in a web page.
In order to enjoy the benefits of intellisense, I'd like to re-wrap the control each time I use the wrapper. (If I wrap it once and set it in a global variable, I lose intellisense the next time I use it in another function - at least in Visual Studio 2008):

```
function onLoad() {
    var control = new Wrapper(form1.button1);
    control.SetColor("Red");
    // etc.
}

function onButton_Clicked() {
    var control = new Wrapper(form1.button1);
    control.SetBackColor("Blue");
    // etc.
}
```

So, to avoid re-creating the wrapper each time for the same control, I first check if it's already been created, and if so return that instance. Below is the pseudo JavaScript code:

```
function Wrapper(control) {

    var i = Wrapper.Controls.IndexOf(control);
    if (i >-1) { return Wrapper.Wrappers[i] };

    // Init stuff

    Wrapper.Controls.Push(control);
    Wrapper.Wrappers.Push(this);

}

Wrapper.prototype.SetColor = function(color) {}
Wrapper.prototype.SetBackColor = function(color) {}
...

Wrapper.Controls = new Array();
Wrapper.Wrappers = new Array();
```

If it is OK to do what I'm doing?  Is there a way to make the static variables, Wrapper.Controls & Wrapper.Wrappers, private?

Comment: As a seperate comment, JavaScript is dynamic. Intellisense tends to get in the way in non-static languages. Just use documentation instead.

Answer (score 0):

Rather then interaction with .NET controls. (No clue what AFWebControl is) I recommend you interact with the DOM instead.

You can use a DOM manipulation library or raw js.

`document.getElementById(id).style.color = ...;`

or

`$("#id").css("color", ...)`

Wait. Is this server-side javascript using ASP ? Please do mark it as serverside if it's so.

To actually answer your question:

```
var cachedfunction = (function() {
    var cache = {};

    return function(arg) {
        return cache[arg] || (cache[arg] = expensivefunction(arg));
    }

}());
```

Here we create a dynamic function with a local cache variable in scope. The function either returns the object from the cache or sets the object in the cache (by expensive call) then returns it.

Comment: Damn! I forgot to rename some functions, so the question made absolutely no sense! I've edited it now. It's nothing to do with server-side or ASP.

Comment: @Jules then don't handle your client side page in terms of ".NET controls". Think of it in terms of nodes in the DOM and handles those nodes through standard DOM manipulation using preferably a library. Again intellisense get's in the way, but feel free to use .vsdoc for jQuery.

Comment: @Jules I actually answered your question about caching.

Comment: (1) Thanks, I'll check out your caching idea. (2) My .Net control is what used to be called an ActiveX control, embedded with an Object Tag. It has many properties and methods which are nothing to do with traditional DOM nodes. This is why providing intellisense for the functions and arguments is very handy.

Comment: @Jules ActiveX controls are evil. It's what keeps IE6 alive. Kill it and re-do it. Please, your helping the web development community.